# Not able to invoke axis2 service from wso2 ESB proxy service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to OSB.

->  I have a AXIS2 webservice application running on wso2 appserver. If we pass a `name` as a parameter it will return `hello +  Name`.

->  I am trying to access this application from proxyservice in WSO2 ESB application.

The project name is `SampleESBConfig` and proxy service name: `ESBtoAxis2PS1`

Steps for Implementing proxy service:

1. The proxy service ha wsdl url :   http://localhost:9763/services/Test1?wsdl ; Wsdl Type:     SOURCE_URL

### InFlow

2. Placed `LogMediator`
3. place `SendMediator`
4. Created address endpoint which points to : http://localhost:9763/services/Test1 [ Target URL, AXIS2 webservice application URL]

### OutFlow

5. Placed `LogMediator`
6. place `SendMediator`

### Fault Sequence

7. Placed the `LogMediator`
8. Created Composite application which includes the above proxyservice
9. Deployed this application on WSO2 ESB server which is running on localhost.

**Note:** 
Both ESB & appserver running on localhost

When i am trying to test the application getting the below error.

> [2015-06-18 16:27:55,212] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during
>   sending message out org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot
>   infer the transport information from the
>   /services/ESBtoAxis2PS1.ESBtoAxis2PS1HttpSoap11Endpoint URL.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you try by removing the WSDL URL

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that your are calling the echo proxy and you are creating a soap project by providing the wsdl of your proxy service.Then the request url for echo service will be
http://localhost:8280/services/echo.echoHttpSoap11Endpoint and when you are going to invoke it, you will get the above error.

As a solution for it  you need to remove the part behind the "." operator. So you proxy calling url will be http://localhost:8280/services/echo

According to the error log I found that you are calling the proxy service */services/ESBtoAxis2PS1.ESBtoAxis2PS1HttpSoap11Endpoint* . So you need to call the proxy like /services/ESBtoAxis2PS1 as I mentioned earlier.

Hope this may solve the issue.